# For my chat app, how would I query these postgres tables so I can get all conversations for a given user id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Tables

#### users

```
id,
...
```

#### messages

```
id, 
sender_id -> users.id,
...
```

#### message_recipients

```
message_id -> messages.id, 
recipient_id -> users.id,
...
```

When given some user_id I want to get all conversations for that user.
Conversation data could look like:

```
message_count, 
other_users_ids -> array of users.id
```

Comment: Hint: Some joins, `GROUP BY`, `count()` and `array_agg()`...

Comment: I'm a sql noob so it's gonna take me a while but thx for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, just this way:

```sql
SELECT users.id, COUNT(1), array_agg(message_recipients.recipient_id) FROM users
INNER JOIN messages ON users.id = messages.sender_id
INNER JOIN message_recipients on messages.id = message_recipients.message_id
GROUP BY users.id;
```